# Import Access Database into VB.NET2010 Application and then refer to it locally?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am writing a program for a class and it needs to read/write to an Access 2007 database. Right now I am referring to it's absolute path when I use it in connection strings, something like:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\Project1\Database.accdb")
```

This is going to be a problem when I turn it in obviously, because the professor isn't going to have the same path. So I want to somehow include it into my project and then refer to it with a relative path or something so that it will work on his machine. When I imported it through the Data Sources it had an option at the end to copy the database into the project which I agreed to. It put the Database where all of the source files are on my computer, so I tried using Application.StartupPath(), but that refers to the folder in bin\Debug when you run the program from Visual Studio (this is not where it put the database). Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this is a bit "hacky" but, if you add it to your solution you can right-click and hit properties. Then make `Copy to Output Directory` = `Copy always` to have it always copied to your output directory. Then you can use Application.StartupPath() like you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, it was already on Copy Always. I just didn't notice it was being copied into the bin\Debug directory.